# Calculating probability for normal variable from coefficient of variation and quantile

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

Given $S$ is a random variable that follows a normal distribution, the coefficient of variation of $S$ being $20\%$ and $P(S \leq 2) = 0.95$, how to find the $P(S\geq 2.5)$ ?

Also, had this distribution been log-normal, instead of normal, how would the probability change in this case?

Comment: This reads rather like routine bookwork. Is this for some class? Do you know the definition of coefficient of variation?

Answer (score 0):

Let's define $S\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Note that each of the two supplied pieces of information correspond to an equation involving $\mu$ and $\sigma$. You should try writing those two pieces of information down as equations involving $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (they are both linear equations so it's pretty simple)

A hint for the second thing -- what value of $Z$ in a standard normal has 95% of the area to its left?

With two equations in two unknowns you should be able to solve for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and hence obtain the probability.

With a lognormal you will have different equations to solve but the general approach is similar.